# Changing the same column of dataframe to int type which contains string like "12Kms" , "13 kms" . Column must contain only numbers like 12, 13

Tags: python, pandas

Below given is a dataframe, in which column C2 contains Strings :

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [[1, "2 Kms"], [3, "4km"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ["C1", "C2"])
df
    C1     C2
0   1    2 Kms
1   3    4km
```

Now i want that in the same dataframe, how could I remove the alphabets in columns C2, the column C2 must contain only numbers 2 at index  0 and 4 at index 1.Column C2 must be of int type. I do not want a new dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract()` with regex to extract the integers, as follows:

```
df['C2'] = df['C2'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   C1  C2
0   1   2
1   3   4
```

Check data type:

```
df['C2'].dtype


dtype('int32')
```

### Edit:

#### In case your `C2` column can contain `NaN` or does not have integer to extract in some elements, you can use:

```
df['C2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C2'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)).astype('Int64')
```

This could **handle `NaN` values in column `C2` and also in case no integer value exists in `C2` where the extraction result will also produce `NaN`**.

Check Data Type:

```
df['C2'].dtype

Int64Dtype()
```

**Demo**

```
lst = [[1, "2 Kms"], [3, "4km"], [5, np.nan], [7, "x km"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ["C1", "C2"])

print(df)

   C1     C2
0   1  2 Kms
1   3    4km
2   5    NaN
3   7   x km

df['C2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C2'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)).astype('Int64')

print(df)

   C1    C2
0   1     2
1   3     4
2   5  <NA>
3   7  <NA>
```